# What's an effective way to filter access.log to return list of unique IP addresses and the number of successful requests (code 200) by each client?

Tags: apache, bash, scripting, awk

I'm looking for a way to take an access.log formatted as shown below

```
127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gig HTTP/1.0" 404 201
127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:56:40 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1406
127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:57:45 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 5325
127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:58:16 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 35292
127.0.0.3 - jerry [10/Oct/2000:13:59:12 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 863
```

and write a script that returns a result formatted like this:

```
127.0.0.1       3
127.0.0.3       1
```

The rules for the script are simple, it should count the number of times each unique IP address logs a successful access request (code 200).

I'm totally open to doing this outside of bash. I just thought it might be easier to start there with grep, sort and uniq. The main issue I've had was that the output uniq -c has is in the wrong format. uniq has been listing output like so:

```
3  127.0.0.1
1  127.0.0.3
```

I can't have that, unfortunately. Any help at all is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '$(NF -1) == 200 {arr[$1]++}END{for (a in arr) print a, arr[a]}' access.log
```

Decomposing it a bit :

- `$(NF -1)` : `awk` by default split current line on spaces (or tabs and such), and `NF` is the numbers of columns, so `NF -1` is the second column one from the right and we test if it's value is 200
- if it's 200, then we increment the associative array `arr` with the IP address as key (`$1` : first column)
- @the end, we print each successful lines

Comment: Added explanations in my POST

Comment: I really like the simplicity of your answer. Thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You got it almost I would use `uniq -c` combined with the stream editor (sed) to reorder the output:

```
grep -E " 200 [0-9]+$" logfile | cut -d\  -f 1 | uniq -c | sed -re "s/^.*([0-9]+) (.*)$/\2 \1/"
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw scripting as a tag so here's a small python script to do that.

```
file_name = "access.log"

ip_counts = {}
with open(file_name) as logfile:
    _ = logfile.readlines()
    for line in _:
        try:
            ip_counts[line.split()[0]] += 1
        except Exception:
            ip_counts[line.split()[0]] = 1

for ip in ip_counts:
    print "%s %s" % (ip, ip_counts[ip])
```

**EDIT:** Oops! Totally forgot about the 200 part. Fixed it now.

```
file_name = "access.log"

ip_counts = {}
with open(file_name) as logfile:
    _ = logfile.readlines()
    for line in _:
        if "200" in line.split():
            try:
                ip_counts[line.split()[0]] += 1
            except Exception:
                ip_counts[line.split()[0]] = 1

for ip in ip_counts:
    print "%s %s" % (ip, ip_counts[ip])
```

Comment: Thank you! Though, I went with the bash method, this script looks great too! Thanks for the helping hand!